# How do I write a program that counts the number of words which has at least 2 vowels in it?

Tags: java, string

I could only find the words with 'x' number of vowels. I need to find number of words containing at least 2 vowel.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter2 =0;
    String acc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string:");
    String[] words = acc.split(" ");
    for(String word : words){
    int counter =0;
     word = word.toLowerCase();
     for (int i =0; i < word.length(); i++){ 
         char x = word.charAt(i);
         if(x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
            x == 'o' || x == 'u'){
             counter++;
          }

     } 
     if (counter >= 2) {
        System.out.println(counter);
```

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: Looks fine to me, it should spit out only words with two vowels...I don't understand what the issue is, are you wanting us to review it?

Comment: Looks fine. Surely you should `println` the word too, just to control that's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're counting the number of vowels and if its >=2, you're printing the vowel counter value instead of printing word count. You can keep track of word counts in the same if condition

```
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            int counter2 =0;
            String acc = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a string:");
            String[] words = acc.split(" ");
            int wordsWithVowels = 0;
            for(String word : words){
              int counter =0;
              int sum=0;
              word = word.toLowerCase();
              for (int i =0; i < word.length(); i++){ 
                 char x = word.charAt(i);
                 if(x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
                    x == 'o' || x == 'u'){
                     counter++;
                  }

              } // end of inner for loop
             if (counter >= 2) {
                wordsWithVowels++;
             }  
          } // // end of outer for loop
      System.out.println("Number of words with 2 or more vowels "+wordsWithVowels);
     } // end of main
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define another counter which will count number of words as you are counting just vowel count. So something like:

```
int numberOfWords = 0;
... for loop
if (counter >= 2) {
    numberOfWords++;    
}
// print numberOfWords
```

Comment: To make that clearer; you'd probably want to define numberOfWords before your loop, and then do this if where you currently print the word.

Comment: Yes agreed and mentioned  in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a count variable and increment it when your counter variable has a value greater equal than 2 . you will get count of words.

And you also might wanna take capital vowels into consideration also.

Comment: OP's doing `word.toLowerCase()` before checking, so that should take care of capital vowels :)